# How one could deploy a word web add in through GPO

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins, office-web-app

Is there a way to deploy a Word Web add in via GPO on premise.
The user should see the add in directly in the start pane.
We have already set the trusted catalog via GPO for the manifest and it is working, but found so far no way to show the user add in automaticly
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPO doesn't provide anything for that. You can read about possible ways in the [Deploy and publish Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish) article.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: “Type: product feature request” at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .